# How to attach to 64-bit process without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

How can I attach a debugger to a running 64-bit .net process without Visual Studio?

I have tried:

- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) but it doesn't allow attachment to 64-bit processes
- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express) but it has no "Attach to process..." option

A JIT debugger that can work with 64-bit .net applications is also good.

The reason I need to do this is I have an application that compiles C# scripts, written by the user of the application, and runs them. I want the the user of the application to be able to debug the scripts but I don't want each application user to need a Visual Studio license for that, so I am looking for a free solution to this problem.

EDIT:

- I also don't want to give the user all my source code but only the binaries.
- The scripts are C# code, compiled in run-time of my application

Comment: I once thought it was a good idea to use C# as a scripting language. Then I found [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). FWIW, PowerShell has built-in debugging support, plus access to all .NET Framework features and libraries.

Comment: Actually, these aren't regular C# scripts but C# source code, compiled in run-time so I can write Debugger.Break() to launch a JIT debugger if available, or attach to the process.

Answer (score 2):

try WinDbg with the **[SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)** extension.  SOS is a managed debugging extension for the old WinDbg debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this workaround](http://www.ninjatrader.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=15671) for Visual Studio Express 2008/2010 help you?